# Applescript Expected “"” but found end of script

Tags: syntax-error, applescript

So, this is what I have wrote so far, the web links are censored for privacy reasons. I made this script so I could have an easy way to access all of my class links. After I told the program to quit after it completed its task, It would not save for the life of me. This is my code:

```
display dialog "Where would you like to go?" buttons {"Math", "English", "Other"} default button 3
set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
if the button_pressed is "Math" then
    display dialog "Select which math you would like to access." buttons {"Math", "Science", "Quit"} default button 3
    set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
    if the button_pressed is "Math" then
        display dialog "Select which math you would like to access." buttons {"Mathway", "Powerschool", "Quit"} default button 3
        set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
        if the button_pressed is "Mathway" then
            tell application "Google Chrome"
                activate
                open location "https://www.mathway.com/Algebra"
            end tell
            delay 1
            tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
            tell application "School Shortcuts" to quit
        else if the button_pressed is "Powerschool" then
            tell application "Google Chrome"
                activate
                open location "_"
            end tell
            delay 1
            tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
        else
            tell application "School Shortcuts" to quit
        end if
    else if the button_pressed is "English" then
        display dialog "Select which math you would like to access." buttons {"Science Calculators", "Powerschool", "Quit"} default button 3
        set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
        if the button_pressed is "Science Calculators" then
            tell application "Google Chrome"
                activate
                open location "https://www.google.com/search?q=science+calculator&oq=science+calculator&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l9.6020j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"
            end tell
            delay 1
            tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
            tell application "School Shortcuts" to quit
        else if the button_pressed is "Powerschool" then
            tell application "Google Chrome"
                activate
                open location "_"
            end tell
            delay 1
            tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
        else
            tell application "School Shortcuts" to quit
        end if
    else
        tell application "School Shortcuts" to quit
    end if
else
    display dialog "Select which you would like to access." buttons {"Spanish", "Comp Tech", "Quit"} default button 3
    set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
    if the button_pressed is "Spanish" then
        display dialog "Spanish" buttons {"Google Classroom", "Translate", "Quit"} default button 3
        set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
        if the button_pressed is "Google Classroom" then
            tell application "Google Chrome"
                activate
                open location "_"
            end tell
            delay 1
            tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
        else if the button_pressed is "Translate" then
            tell application "Google Chrome"
                activate
                open location "https://www.google.com/search?q=translate&oq=translate&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0j0i433j0j0i433j69i60l3.1944j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"
            end tell
            delay 1
            tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
        else
            tell application "School Shortcuts" to quit
        end if
    else if the button_pressed is "Comp Tech" then
        display dialog "Comp Tech" buttons {"Google Classroom", "Youtube", "Quit"} default button 3
        set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
        if the button_pressed is "Google Classroom" then
            tell application "Google Chrome"
                activate
                open location "_"
            end tell
            delay 1
            tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
            
        else if the button_pressed is "Youtube" then
            tell application "Google Chrome"
                activate
                open location "youtube.com"
            end tell
            delay 1
            tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
        else
            tell application "School Shortcuts" to quit" to quit
        end if
        
    else
        
    end if
    
end if


end
```

If you have any idea on why it is doing this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Edit: I currently reverted to where I chose the application to quit, and it compiled.

Answer (score 0):

The error

> Expected “"” but found end of script

indicates an unbalanced double quote.

At the end of the script there it is

```
tell application "School Shortcuts" to quit" to quit
```

Delete the (last) double quote and the rest of the line

```
tell application "School Shortcuts" to quit
```